# Linux toolbox to perform network analysis?

Tags: network-monitoring, tools, desktop-apps

Are there any good tools that I can use to analyze the network - like a network administrator - and also display information about switches, computers and the server?

I found LinSSID for the WLAN, but I don't have an idea for the network yet. I'm trying to get a deeper insight and, if necessary, would like to be able to speak to the service provider on an equal footing.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question with more focus. There are numerous Linux network analysis tools including wireshark, tcpdump, nmap but it depends on what you want to achieve.